# How to center the image link inside div

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, center

I'm trying to center image link inside div, but something going wrong.

My code:

```
<div id="screenshots">
    <figure class="sreenshot">
           <a href="/img/products_screenshots/15/opportunity.png" rel="screenshots" class="fancybox"><img alt="" id="screenshot0" src="/img/products_screenshots/15/opportunity.png"></a>
           <figcaption>Карточка "Продажи"</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Which styles should be to each block of the picture to the middle of `class="sreenshot"`?
Now it's looks like this [Screencast](http://screencast.com/t/rm61vQu9cgPz)

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to see your code, as long as your link and image are set to `display: inline;` you should be able to use `text-align: center` on the parent element to make it appear central to it's container.